# Iterating over jQuery selector with variable, using closures

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, closures

[First time on stackoverflow.] I am trying to dynamically add html buttons to my page and then give them a javascript function to run when they are clicked, using jQuery's click. I want to have one button for each element in an array, so I used a for loop. My code looks like this (simplified)

```
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    $("#" + place[i].place_id).click(function(){console.log("Test");})        
    $("#" + place[i].place_id).click();
}
```

(I inject buttons with the right id's in the same loop.) This code, when run, console logs "Test" the right number of times, but afterwards, only the last button responds "Test" when clicked. (This situation is a little absurd.) So, I think the event handler ends up using only the final value of i to assign the event handler. I think the problem has to do with closures, but I am not sure how to make a closure out of a jQuery Selector (and in general am not familiar with them).

In contrast, as a hack solution, I "manually" wrote code like the below right below and outside the for loop, and it works as expected, in that clicking causes the console log.

```
$("#" + place[0].place_id).click(function(){console.log("Test"););
$("#" + place[1].place_id).click(function(){console.log("Test");});
etc.
```

(Of course, this all occurs within a larger context - specifically a Google Maps Places API call's callback.)

First, am I understanding the problem correctly? Second, what would work? Should I take a different approach altogether, like use a .each()?

(I later would want to display a property of place[i] when clicked, which I would think would need another callback
My final hack code looks like this:

```
$("#" + place[0].place_id).click(function(){google.maps.event.trigger(placeMarkers[0], "click"); repeated 20 times
```

Comment: it works fine in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/koj2efmg/)

Comment: [Creating closures in loops: A common mistake](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3A_A_common_mistake)

Comment: [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you can simply create a self executing function inside the for loop, like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    (function(index) {
        $("#" + place[index].place_id).click(function() { 
            //Do something with place[index] here 
        });
    })(i);
}
```